# Get json from HTML and preapre array to send by js

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a table

```
<table class="cart-table core_storeCartProducts" data-minimal-order-price="0" data-products="{1912c6c3:{amount:1,id:1916,options:{}},17014bb1:{amount:1,id:3231,options:{}},0b2a5c4b:{amount:1,id:4122,options:{}}}">
```

and i need to take id from data-products and next send to cart.php. 
somebody have any idea ?

Comment: Please edit your question and make it more readable...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#JavaScript_access

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Comment: P.S which ID do you want to send? All of them?

Answer (score 0):

get element attribute and parse data

```
var idList = [];
       var productArray = JSON.parse(document.getElementsByClassName("core_storeCartProducts")[0].getAttribute('data-products')); //get attribute and parse data  

       for (const i in productArray) {
          idList.push(productArray[i]['id']); //collect all product id
        }
        console.log(idList);
// pass idList to php using ajax
```

Answer (score -1):

use JQuery + JSON parse function

```
var data = $("table").attr("data-products"); // get string
data = JSON.parse(data); // convert to JSON
var id = data.1912c6c3.id; // get id
```

now Send it to your cart.php via AJAX

```
$.ajax({
url: 'cart.php',
data: {idToSend: id},
success:function(response){
//handle the response
},
error: function(err){
// handle the error code
}
});
```

Comment: OP didn't mention that they had jQuery available. They may not wish to use it. If it's not mentioned generally you should offer a plain-JS solution

Comment: todays JQuery is available to every one @ADyson

Comment: It's available to download, but that doesn't mean everyone is using it, or wants to use it, or is allowed to use it in their project. It's far better to give someone a solution they can definitely use. If the question is tagged jQuery, then a jQuery solution is fine, if not then don't. You wouldn't randomly give them an AngularJS-based solution if that wasn't mentioned, would you?

Comment: agree... but **JQuery** is almost allowed in general projects

Comment: we have no idea what kind of project this is, and what constraints there are. Or it could just be OP may have written everything else in raw JS or using some other library and not want to use jQuery for one random bit like this. It would have been better to leave a comment and ask if they would accept a jQuery answer. OTOH it's not that hard to re-write this as raw JS, if you have 2 minutes. Also I'm guessing it should probably send all the IDs, not just one